# .htaccess rewrite rules that include a sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I have 2 apps running on my site one at root `/` and one at at `/blog/`.

I want to be able to access some pages that are served by the blog app but without the /blog/ part in the URL. This bit I have managed to do with the following rule.

```
RewriteRule my-page blog/index\.php?page_id=1 [L]
```

This allows me to view a page actually at `/blog/my-page` at `/my-page`.

Now where I'm struggling is with ensuring there are no duplicate URLs, so I'm trying to redirect to my shorter URL. Like so:

From:

```
/blog/my-page
```

To:

```
/my-page
```

From:

```
/blog/index.php?page_id=1
```

To:

```
/my-page
```

With the following rule, I can redirect from `/index.php?page_id=1` to `/my-page`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=1$
RewriteRule index\.php$ my-page? [R=301,L]
```

After this rule happens the first rule I mentioned takes it to the right place.

### My question is:

How can I get it to work with `blog` as part of the URL. I expected the below to work but it doesn't

```
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=1$
RewriteRule ^blog/index\.php$ my-page? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your previous rule is overwriting it `RewriteRule index\.php$ my-page? [R=301,L]` this will match anything that ends with `index.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this was not working was because there was an `.htaccess` file within my `/blog/` directory.

This included a rule that would catch anything and route to `blog/index.php`.

Moving my rules to `/blog/.htaccess` allowed them to function properly